# How to import data from one db to another db?

Tags: python, mysql, database, web

There are two databases. Call them as A and B. 
A is a backend db which is populated with a web crawler. The data in db A will be published to db B after audited.  The db B will serve the front-end application, which is the layer of the end user write/read.

The question: what's the best solution to implement this feature: import/publish data from one db to another db.

I searched some solutions:

1. use mysqldump to dump the data, then import the data. 
   My concern is this solution needs to refresh DB every import process. If we have some modifications in db B not do in db A. The modifications in db B will be overwritten
2. use workbench or phpmyadmin. 
   These two methods are not fit for our application.

Do you have some good suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to keep some data, how do you plan to resolve "merge conflicts"

Comment: Yes, I have no idea for this. Any ideas?

Comment: A general solution (one that reads your mind) isn't possible. Explain the details of what modifications might happen and what you want to do in those cases. (http://xkcd.com/568/, panel 2).

Comment: For instance, the data from db A has some errors, I mean the data need to be corrected in db B. So the modification happens in db B. I feel all the modifications could be done in db A. db B is just a copy of db A.  This will be simple and ignore the complex conflict merge between two sources.

Comment: Are two databases really necessary here?  Why not a simply have a "published" flag, initially false, which is set to true once the content has been edited/approved?

Comment: As the data is crawled by web crawler. The crawler writes the db frequently. Till now, the main operation on frontend application is read. We separate these two dbs.